# how to use python's Request library to make an API call with an attachment and a parameter

Tags: python-2.7, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am using the Request library to test ReST APIs. I am facing a problem while trying to trasform the below cURL to request library Call.

curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F parent_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID

I tried many of the suggestions in this forum. But nothing worked.

The code which I addedd after the comment is:

The code I wrote was:

`def upload_a_file(url, folder_id, file_name, access_token):`
    field_values = "{\'filename\': (filename, open("+file_name+", \'rb\'))}"
`payload = "{\'parent_id\':"+folder_id+"}"`
    request_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}
`result = requests.post(url, headers=request_headers, data=payload, files=field_values)`
    response = result.json()
`print response`

Comment: Why are you storing payload, etc as strings? See my original example; requests is expecting a dict. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library?

If so, here is how I do it.

```
access_token = <user access token>
filename = <name of the file as you want it to appear on Box>
src_file = the actual file path
parent_id = the id of the folder you want to upload to

headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token) }
url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content'
files = { 'filename': (filename, open(src_file,'rb')) }
data = { "parent_id": parent_id }
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
file_info = response.json()
```

Comment: Can you provide any more details...? Are you using the requests package? Have you authenticated your app? I will modify the above to clarify the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example given in http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/67408/Show-progress-bar-when-uploading-a-file.

I was able to make a successful API call.