# Having trouble uploading files with Box.com API

Tags: python, python-3.x, box-api, boxapiv2

I am new to programming and learning python, so please bear with me, I appreciate the help....

I am working on a project where I need to upload files to storage services and I am currently trying to use the box API.  I am trying to work with the code on this page:

[how to use python's Request library to make an API call with an attachment and a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942163/how-to-use-pythons-request-library-to-make-an-api-call-with-an-attachment-and-a)

```
import requests
import json

#the user access token
access_token =  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#the name of the file as you want it to appear in box
filename = 'box_file'
#the actual file path
src_file = "C:\Python\Wildlife.wmv"
#the id of the folder you want to upload to
parent_id = '0'

headers = { 'Authorization: Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)}
url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content'
files = { 'filename': (filename, open(src_file,'rb')) }
data = { "parent_id": parent_id }
response = requests.post(url, data, files, headers)
file_info = response.json()
```

I have tried a number of different things that really haven't gotten me any closer, so I am posting my slight adaptation of their code.  Currently I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer2.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, data, files, headers)
TypeError: post() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I have also had issues with the file_info = response.json()" in some of my other experiments.  If someone could help me to get this working I would greatly appreciate it.

I am using python 3 if that helps.

***edit 4/6***
As requested, I changed this line:
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)

This is the error I now get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer2.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 450, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 381, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 305, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 410, in prepare_headers
    self.headers = CaseInsensitiveDict((to_native_string(name), value) for name, value in headers.items())
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: There's also a new [Box Python SDK](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk) which might make using the API a bit easier. There's an example for how to upload a file [here](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/blob/master/demo/example.py).

Comment: Greg, Is it possible to upload all files in a specified directory with the SDK?

Comment: I don't think there is. You'll need to iterate over the files in your folder and upload each one separately. If you have other questions specific to the Python SDK, I'd suggest posting a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the requests library for `request.post()`, headers and files are both keyword arguments only, I would also make data a keyword argument, e.g.:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Headers needs to be a dictionary and you have created a `set()`, try `headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2
oauth = OAuth2( client_id="dlpjkcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcom",client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", )
client = Client(oauth)
shared_folder = client.folder(folder_id='0',).create_subfolder('sxxxx')
uploaded_file = shared_folder.upload('/root/xxxxxx.txt')
```

Comment: Welcome aboard! A code-only answer is not considered to be good style in StackOverflow. Please add a bit of explanation and description of your snippet.